# Why is there no ASP .NET session cookie in response on login page?

Tags: asp.net, session

In my ASP .NET web application, when I first navigate to the login page, I do not see a Set-Cookie header coming back in the response from the server. I expect to see one that looks something like:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=efypn5ihkam3pdcuucmbykvi; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Here is my sessionState config entry in the web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="480"/>
```

I've cleared my cookies in my browser, then navigated to the login page. No Set-Cookie. After I log in to the application, it does send a cookie back for session tracking.

Other apps I've built work fine...this one is giving me trouble. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, the session state isn't started until you create your first session state variable, which usually begins with authentication (after logging in). Unless your deliberately creating a sessionstate variable on the login page request, you shouldn't see one until you actually log in.

Comment: "the session state isn't started until you create your first session state variable" - correct, UNLESS you have a `Session_Start` handler set in Global.asax, then the session is *always* started

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem that when I signed in with local host iis there were no problem but when I signed in with my site the session cookie and login cookie was not set.
The problem was in web.config that I hadn't sync that with my webserver.